# Getting error when using read only bind mound for creating docker container

Tags: docker

I am creating a container with the following command, and I am trying to create a read-only bind mount in that container.

**the command for creating the bind mount container**

```
docker run -v $(pwd):/app:ro -v /app/node_modules -p 8081:3000 -d  --name node-app node-app-image
```

**Error:**

```
5962ac6ca3e13101b64c8e756b12d21ee7e29d6834e6b881989c3ff1386c267b
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused: rootfs_linux.go:76: mounting "/var/lib/docker/volumes/d656c9a83c95caf16c2530e9fd752a2a8d2789c552201e5084ed1acdde0a3552/_data" to rootfs at "/app/node_modules" caused: mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay2/e6a25730b11babe3a1df83a1513d020f71cb74762b59cb06bcecc97b0d54abb8/merged/app/node_modules: read-only file system: unknown.
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your version of Docker and exact OS, but a similar error was followed by [`docker/for-linux` issue 1124](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/1124) and upgrading Docker was enough.

That was linked with [moby issue 41541](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/41541) ("Failed to set OOM Score on shim: write /proc/226/oom_score_adj: permission denied")
(OOM: Out Of Memory)